# uploading a i-phone application to apple store?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

i have been trying to uplaod an application to apple store for 2 days now..first they said the provisioning profile was not right due to which i had to make a new one and upload it again now after that problem was solved while uploading the new binary it said the version was same with the previous minor version(1.0 - which someone else uploaded in my company)..then i changed the version to 1.1 by changing it in target > info > properties..then i cleaned all targets quite the xcode,restarted the xcode and build the project again..it succeeded and now wen i uploaded it it still says the same error

> version same with the previous minor version

is there any other way of changing the version number though in my info.plist file it is showing version:1.1??

i am all new to iphone and the person who created the application is not here and i dont have any CFbundleversion in my info.plist which some people suggested me to update??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately you can change CFBundleShortVersion string in app-info.plist file and increment it. I have faced the same problem earlier. This property is not present by default and needs to be added.

Bundle versions string, short is the parameter name

Comment: should i change CFBundleShortversion to 1.1 too same as my present changed bundle version???

Answer (score 1):

Change your version from 1.1 to 1.1.1 or 1.2  For each new binary, your version number should increase. How to increase version numbers will depends on your versioning system.